# Sharing url on Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest

Tags: angularjs, laravel, facebook, twitter, pinterest

I started development to share an edited image on Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest.

We have a learning management system(LMS) which is developed using Angularjs, a front website developed using Laravel and set of APIs.

After the user logs into the LMS user can share referral code on Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest. To share a referral code, we use an image. Every time we add users' referral code to image and share it. Image processing is done by the front site. Therefore I'm setting URL of front site view which creates an image with a referral code and use it to share on social media.

Sharing code as follows (LMS)

**Directive**

```
    <share-referrer></share-referrer>

    skApi.directive('shareReferrer', function ($window, $cookies, skApiService, $location, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.share_referral_url = "";
            scope.share_pinterest_referral_url = "";
            scope.share_referral_pinterest_image_url = "";

             $http({
                 method: 'POST',
                 url: skApiService.getApiUrl('lms')+'/referrals/get-user-referral-details',
                 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
             }).then(function successCallback(respond) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                 if (respond.data.success == true){
                        scope.refer_first_name = [];
                        scope.refer_first_name_email = [];

                        scope.share_referral_url = respond.data.share_referral_url;
                        scope.share_pinterest_referral_url = respond.data.share_pinterest_referral_url;
                        scope.referral_code = respond.data.data.code;
                        scope.share_referral_pinterest_image_url = respond.data.share_referral_pinterest_image_url;
                        console.log(scope.share_referral_url);
                 }else if (respond.data.success == false){
                    scope.hide_message = false;
                    scope.message_section_class = "alert alert-danger";
                    scope.error_message = respond.data.message;
                 }
             }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
             });

             scope.$watch(scope.share_referral_url ,function(newValue, oldValue){
                 console.log("share referral url ", newValue, oldValue);
             });

             /*Share on pinterest*/
             scope.pinIt = function(){
                var pinterest_url = scope.share_pinterest_referral_url+"&type=pinterest";

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: pinterest_url,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
                });
                //This code from pinterest
                PinUtils.pinOne({
                   'url': pinterest_url, 
                   'media': scope.share_referral_pinterest_image_url, 
                   'description': 'Next stop: Pinterest!' 
                });
                //End pinterest
             };
        },
        scope: {
            share_referral_url: '@',
            share_referral_pinterest_image_url: '@', 
            referral_code: '@',         
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/social-media-share.html'
    };
});
```

**directives/social-media-share.html**

```
<div class="share_on_section">
<div>
    <span>Share on:</span>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=699323760416619&autoLogAppEvents=1';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="{{share_referral_url}}&type=facebook" 
    data-layout="button_count">
</div>

<div class="pinterest_share_block">
    <script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>           
    <a ng-click="pinIt()"><img src="images/icon_64x64.png" width="20" height="20"></a>                      
</div>

<div class="twitter_share_block">       
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <a class="twitter-share-button"
      href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"
      data-text="Refer a friend"
      data-url="{{share_referral_url}}&amp;type=twitter"
      data-hashtags="ssss">Tweet</a>        
</div>
```

According to type GET variable we identify a type of social media in front laravel site and add text to an image. We set that image in the relevant view file. There are three view files.

**share_code_facebook.blade.php**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>sssss</title>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Refer a friend" />
<meta property="og:description"
    content="I'm loving ddd and you'll love it too! Subscribe now to it to get access to over 18,000 resources aligned to the sss sss. Use the referral code {{$social_media->getReferralCode()}} to let them know that I sent you. Happy ssss!" />
<!--  <meta property="og:image:url"         content="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" />-->
<meta property="og:image:url"
    content="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Refer a friend" />
<!-- <meta property="og:image:height" content="750" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" /> -->
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="222222" />
<meta property="og:url"
    content="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" />
```

**share_code_twitter.blade.php**

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>sssss</title>
        <link rel="me" href="https://twitter.com/22222">

        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@dddd" />
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@ddddd" />

        <meta name="twitter:title" content="Refer a friend from Twitter" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="I'm loving dddd and you'll love it too! Subscribe now to it to get access to over 18,000 resources aligned to the sss dddd. Use the referral code {{$social_media->getReferralCode()}} to let them know that I sent you. Happy sssss!" />
        <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" />
        <!-- <meta name="twitter:player" content="{{env('APP_URL')}}" />-->
<!--    <meta name="twitter:player:width" content="720" />
        <meta name="twitter:player:height" content="480" />-->
        <meta property="og:url" content="{{env('APP_URL')}}share-referral-code?referral_code={{$social_media->getReferralCode()}}&type=twitter&return=twitter" />
</head>
<div>
    <img alt="Refer a friend on pinterest" src="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" 
    class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;"/>
</div>
```

**share_code_pinterest.blade.php**

```
<div>
<img alt="Refer a friend on pinterest" src="{{env('APP_URL')}}{{$social_media->getImageShared()}}" 
class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;"/>
```

These sharing functionality is working fine. In every shared post these social media set URL what I shared from LMS. But Facebook add fbid end of the URL. But others(twitter and Pinterest) don't set a parameter to identify it. Is there param or anyway to identify it?

Comment: Yes, Facebook adds tracking parameters to outgoing links. But what about this do you want to “identify”? You can check if the parameter is present, if you like – but so far unclear why you would want to do that. (And why so much code and elaboration in the first place, if an unclear question about this tracking parameter seems to be more or less the main point here?)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. As I said, every social media sets shared url as a link to post. Therefore after user click on post, request goes same as when it was sharing. Therefore we need to identify the request.

Comment: That I understand even less now. _What_ do you need to “identify”?

Comment: Another thing is sharing image is not a static image. We need to add text on it every time when user is going to share

Comment: @04FS Lets say I shared url /share-referral-code?referral_code=P3333333T&type=twitter. Twitter also set this as a link in the post. When user click on it we can't identify where it comes from. But Facebook adds a parameter. LMS is not visible to outside. User need to log into see content. That's why we handle request in front site. I think you can understand.

Comment: If you post the same URL to different networks, then of course you will not be able to determine this by the URL alone. Either see if you get a referrer for those links - or share different URLs to the different networks in the first place, if you need to be able to differentiate this.

Comment: I'm using type GET variable to identify it when sharing. But every network link url what i'm sharing. The 'type' variable differs for network(type=facebook, type=twitter etc.)

Comment: I think you are taking about $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] server variable. Is there any other better option when sharing on social media? sharing parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188732/discussion-between-cha-and-04fs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @04FS said I checked 'HTTP_REFERER' server variable of request object in laravel controller to identify referer as follows

```
    $data = $request->all();
    $http_referrer = parse_url($request->server('HTTP_REFERER'));

    //For facebook
    if( isset($data['fbclid'])){
        return redirect('/?return='.$data['fbclid']."&type=".$data['type']."&referral_code=".$data['referral_code']);
    }

    //For Twitter
    if(isset($http_referrer['host']) &&  $http_referrer['host'] != NUll && $http_referrer['host'] == 't.co'){
        return redirect('/?return=twitter&type='.$data['type']."&referral_code=".$data['referral_code']);
    }

    //For Pinterest
    if( isset($http_referrer['host']) &&  $http_referrer['host'] != NUll && $http_referrer['host'] == 'www.pinterest.com'){
        return redirect('/?return=pinterest&type='.$data['type']."&referral_code=".$data['referral_code']);
    }
```